# GrayLog2 : How to Externalize dashboard?

Tags: web-applications, embed, external, dashboard, graylog

I have used Kibana, here i was able to externalize the dashboard and embed the same in some other application. Is there a possibility to do the same on GrayLog?
Please help!

Comment: Actually Kibana provides HTML code corresponding to the dashboard and this code can be embedded in external applications. Can the same be done using GrayLog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confirmed with the graylog community. This feature is not supported currently.